# Youtube iFrame 'player' object's methods aren't accessible, what could be the reason?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

As you can see in the image, on printing the player object in console it shows all the methods but when I print keys separately, they aren't accessible. This is to show that **player object's methods** are not working. What should I do?

```
var player = {};

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady1(v) {
   player = new YT.Player('player', {
   height: '390',
   width: '640',
   events: {
      //'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      },
      origin: "http://localhost",
   });
   if (player.D == 'player'){
      makePlaylist(v);      //This is to make sure that the player object has been created.
   }
}


function makePlaylist(videos){
   console.log('makePlaylist', videos, player);
   for (x in player){
      console.log(x);
   }
   player.loadVideoById(videos);
   player.playVideo();
}
```

[image]

Comment: In your console output, there is neither a `loadVideoById()` nor a `playVideo()`.  Why do you expect them to be there?

Comment: That's the problem. The object's console.log output shows all the available methods just fine. But I print all the keys individually with **for x in y loop**, the methods don't come up.

Comment: There's not enough to see in your screenshot, but is it possible those are the members of `videos`, not `player`?

Comment: Nope, the top part of the screenshot has a snippet of methods just to show that the player object is a genuine object of the YT Player class. And bottom part of the screenshot is to show that printing out Keys of the this object separately doesn't show the methods. Moreover, when I call any of the methods from console, it works. e.g **player.playVideo()** start playing a cued video.